# External command doesn't run in GUI mode

Tags: bash

I have the following function attached to `f2` key in latex mode:

```
(defun latex-compile ()
      "Runs pdflatex on current file"
      (interactive)
      (let* ((file-name (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name)))
            (process (start-process-shell-command
                           "pdflatex"
                           "*async pdflatex*"
                           (concat "pdflatex " file-name))))
            (set-process-sentinel process 'latex-sentinel)
            (setq new-window (split-window-below 30))
            (set-window-buffer new-window "*async pdflatex*")
            (other-window 1)
            (set-process-query-on-exit-flag process nil)
            (local-set-key (kbd "z") 'latex-kill-async-pdflatex)
            ))
```

`pdflatex` program is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux`. I have the following in .bash_profile and .bashrc:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux
```

When I click `<f2>` in GUI Emacs, it says: "/usr/bin/bash: pdflatex: command not found".

But in console Emacs it works.

I have also added

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux")))
```

to .emacs, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec-path` is how Emacs finds executables, but you're not asking Emacs to find `pdflatex`, you're only asking it to find a shell, and the shell is then trying to run `pdflatex`.

The shell will be using the `PATH` in its environment. Your problem is probably that the way in which you start your GUI Emacs does not involve setting that `PATH` value in its environment, whereas when you start terminal Emacs you're doing so from a bash session in which your bash init files have run.

(How *do* you start your GUI Emacs?)

You can either ensure that when GUI Emacs is started it has the desired PATH, or else you can set the value in the `process-environment` variable in Emacs using `setenv`.

You can do this temporarily for a command if you prefer. e.g.:

```el
(let ((process-environment (copy-sequence process-environment)))
  (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux"))
  (start-process-shell-command "path" "*path*" "echo $PATH"))
```

---

A modified version of the original function might look like:

```el
(defun latex-compile ()
  "Runs pdflatex on current file"
  (interactive)
  (let ((process-environment (copy-sequence process-environment)))
    (setenv "PATH" "$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux" t)
    (let* ((file-name (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name)))
           (process (start-process-shell-command
                     "pdflatex"
                     "*async pdflatex*"
                     (concat "pdflatex " file-name))))
      (set-process-sentinel process 'latex-sentinel)
      (setq new-window (split-window-below 30))
      (set-window-buffer new-window "*async pdflatex*")
      (other-window 1)
      (set-process-query-on-exit-flag process nil)
      (local-set-key (kbd "z") 'latex-kill-async-pdflatex))))
```

Comment: "(How do you start your GUI Emacs?)" - clicking the icon in KDE start panel.

Comment: In which case I would start searching on KDE support forums for how to pass the environment configured by your bash init files to a process started from the KDE start panel, if you wish to pursue that approach.

Comment: I have already added it to environment system wide by adding `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux"))` to .emacs. Now it works.

Comment: Is it possible to set it locally using let*? Can you modify my function latex-compile? I tried to add your code, but it didn't work